# Вопрос про установку файлов с сайта для Python

Tags: python, download

Нужно, чтобы с сайта устанавливался файл в папку с игрой(например в skyrim). Но проблема в том, что  у людей папка с игрой может находиться в любом месте, в любой их директории, куда они установили игру. Подскажите пожалуйста, как в этом случае поступить. Если что-то не понятно могу объяснить( пишу сразу не надо писать про автосоздание новой папки, мне это не нужно, так как файлы игры не будут в ней). Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь достаточно перенести .py файл в директорию с игрой, чтобы он действовал непосредственно в локальной директории игры.

Comment: Не подходит. Я его в exe переведу. И так быть не должно.

Comment: @Сергей тогда может добавить конфигурационный файл, и задавать пользователю вопрос с расположением игры?

Comment: Тоже не вариант. Я хочу чтобы была относительная директория для установки. Например есть на 2-ух компах разные директории D:\BB и C:\ВВ и файл должен загружаться в BB

Comment: @Сергей значит найти в реестре инфу по файлам игры. других вариантов не вижу.